# Is it possible to use member function call as default argument?

Tags: c++, member-functions, default-arguments

Here is my code:

```
struct S
{
   int f() { return 1; }
   int g(int arg = f()) { return arg; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    return s.g();
}
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
error: cannot call member function 'int S::f()' without object
```

Trying `this->f()` doesn't work either, as `this` may not be used in that context.

Is there a way to make this work, still using the default argument?

---

Of course it can be worked around by not using default arguments at all:

```
int g(int arg) { return arg; }
int g() { return g(f()); }
```

however that gets verbose considering that in the "real code" there are more parameters before `arg`, and several functions following this pattern. (And even more ugly if there were multiple default arguments in the one function).

NB. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502745/cannot-pass-my-member-function-as-default-parameter-for-my-template-class-c) looks similar at first, but in fact he is asking how to form a closure, which is a different problem (and the linked solution doesn't apply to my situation).

Comment: It should be `int g() { return g(f()); }`, right? At least, in the real code, it would make much sense maybe. Of course, here it works for you have only the `return` statement in `g`.

Comment: @skypjack thanks, fixed

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only use members there if they are `static`. From a C++11 draft standard (n3299), §8.3.6/9:

> Similarly, a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the *id-expression* of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it is
> used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1).

E.g., this works:

```
struct S {
  static int f() { return 1; }
  int g(int arg = f()) { return arg; }
};

int main()
{
  S s;
  return s.g();
}
```

This also works (I think that's what the first expression means):

```
struct S {
  int f() { return 42; }
  int g(int arg);
};

static S global;

int S::g(int arg = global.f()) { return arg; }

int main()
{
  S s;
  return s.g();
}
```

As for `this`, it is indeed not allowed (§8.3.6/8):

> The keyword `this` shall not be used in a default argument of a member function.

The [default arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) page on cppreference.com has a lot of details regarding the subject—it can get quite complex.

Answer (score 6):

If you are allowed to use experimental features from C++17, you can use `std::optional` from the STL (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for further details).

In other terms something like:

```
int g(std::optional<int> oarg = std::optional<int>{}) {
    int arg = oarg ? *oarg : f();
    // go further
}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, the code above should be logically equivalent to the one below:

```
int g(std::optional<int> oarg = std::optional<int>{}) {
    int arg = oarg.value_or(f());
    // go further
}
```

This one is a bit more readable (isn't it?), but please note that it executes `f` in any case.
If that function is expensive, maybe it doesn't worth it.

Comment: Oops, in my real code the argument is taken by const reference, rather than by value. I didn't realize this was going to make a difference at first. I think your solution would still apply though (can change the wrapped type to `reference_wrapper` or something)

Comment: @M.M Yeah, it still applies. Anyway, I've added another answer that offers maybe an even better solution (at least, a point from which to start). Let me know if it's a suitable approach for you.

Comment: Just a little suggestion - I think that `value_or` should be used instead of `?:` in cases like this.

Comment: @Predelnik Right, I'm updating the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I add another answer, that is completely different from the previous one and could solve your issue.
The idea is to use another class and the right mix of explicit and non-explicit constructors.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class C, int(C::*M)()>
struct Arg {
    std::function<int(C*)> fn;
    Arg(int i): fn{[i](C*){ return i; }} { } 
    explicit Arg(): fn{[](C* c){ return (c->*M)(); }} { }
};

struct S {
    int f() { return 1; }
    int h() { return 2; }
    void g(int arg0,
          Arg<S, &S::f> arg1 = Arg<S, &S::f>{},
          Arg<S, &S::h> arg2 = Arg<S, &S::h>{})
    {
        std::cout << "arguments" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "arg0: " << arg0 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "arg1: " << arg1.fn(this) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "arg2: " << arg2.fn(this) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    s.g(42, 41, 40);
    s.g(0);
}
```

The example shows how you can mix both default parameters and non defaulted ones.
It's quite simple to modify it and let `g` be a function having an empty argument list, as in the original question.
I'm also quite sure that one can refine the example and end with something better than that, anyway it should be a good point from which to start.

It follows the solution applied to the original example from the question:

```
#include <functional>

template<class C, int(C::*M)()>
struct Arg {
    std::function<int(C*)> fn;
    Arg(int i): fn{[i](C*){ return i; }} { } 
    explicit Arg(): fn{[](C* c){ return (c->*M)(); }} { }
};

struct S {
    int f() { return 1; }
    int g(Arg<S, &S::f> arg = Arg<S, &S::f>{}) {
        return arg.fn(this);
    }
};

int main() {   
    S s{}; 
    return s.g();
}
```

And that's all, it's possible to do that, even without `static` methods or global variables.
Of course, we can use our *this* somehow. It's a matter of bending the language a bit...